# Child Job to always run in parent workspace Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 different parent jobs and 1 child job. As my parent job and child shares same workspace, i do not want code to be built again while running Child Job and child to use same workspace as parent.
I tried using [Shared Workspace Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) however in this plugin we need to define different workspace and will have to change my workspace accordingly in my child job. I do not want to manually change my workspace in child job everytime i run my different parent jobs.
Is there any way in Jenkins to always have child pull workspace from parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a parameter in the child called "Workspace_Home", and send it from the parent job to the child using [trigger's plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) - add pre-defined parameters :

```
Workspace_Home=$WORKSPACE
```

In the child you can configure the job to run under custom workspace (it's in Configure Job --> Advance (before SCM section), add the parameter ${Workspace_Home} and that's it!

Just make sure when you're triggering the job to specify "Run on the same node" in order for it to run on the same slave.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you mean define a parameter in parent with name of "Workspace_Home" and then pass it on to child?

Comment: This solution is not working for me. $Workspace in not sending anything.

Comment: Apologies, try $WORKSPACE. this is an environmental parameter in the job that Jenkins is generating to save the workspace of the job. You can view all environmental parameters of the job once it's finished by going into the instance of the job that ran and search for the "Environmental Parameters" in left side of the view.

Comment: This is working somewhat but not exactly what i want. If i want to run child alone sometime, it is not taking my parent job workspace in that case because parent job was not run. Is there any other solution which can work when i try to run child alone or both parent and child together?

Comment: Just assign a default value in your child job to the workspace you send from the parent. Then you can only build the child. again you will need to specify the node you're running on in order to run on the same machine or add a restriction to where the child job can run. It also seems to me it'll be wiser not to work with a parent->child jobs, but with a wrapper job that holds both parent and child. so wrapper controls the environment, workspace, machines to run, etc. first job conditional trigger if you want it to run or not, same as second, then you just run the wrapper

Comment: Adding default value worked for me. I do not have much information on building a wrapper. Can you please point me with some examples?

Comment: It's just another job that triggers both of your jobs :) as I understood from your scenario you want to choose when to trigger the parent job or not, you can use conditional plugin to check Boolean value if to trigger the job or not. that you you run the "wrapper" job with a check box to either run your parent job or not, and then trigger the child job from the wrapper as well. I hope I'm making myself clear...